# C++ Header file template

Tags: c++

I am using a template in a header file. The function I am using is recursive and I would like to keep two variables outside of the function to compare against. Here is my code (note: does not compile):

```
#include "Position.h"
#ifndef _SOLVER_H
#define _SOLVER_H

class Solver{
  public:
    template<typename T>
    int EvaluatePosition(T &p, bool me) {
        int score = 0;
        if(p.isGameOver()) {
            return p.score(me);
        }
        else {
            std::vector<T> nextMoves = p.getNextPositions();
            for(int i=0; i != nextMoves.size(); i++) {
                score += EvaluatePosition(nextMoves[i],!me);
                if(score > maxScore) {
                    p.display();
                    maxScore = score;
                    maxP = p;
                    p.display();
                }
            }
            return score;
        }
    }

    T maxP; // Want this to be the same Type T that is used in the function
    int maxScore;
};

#endif
```

I am trying to create a variable of the same generic type as the `T` used in the function so that I can save out some data. Is this possible, and if it is, how would it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your whole class a templated one, not just the function.

```
template< class T > class Solver{
    //here goes your function that takes the argument of T class
    int EvaluatePosition(T &p, bool me){
        //...
    }

    T maxP; //here goes your variable
    int maxScore;
};
```

Comment: This affects the call site (type deduction will no longer occur). Also, it is not _necessary_ (see my answer for an alternative that hides the implementation details)

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, template the entire class. Assuming you don't like that call-interface, you could use a local template class to hold the state:

```
class Solver{
  public:
    template<typename T> int EvaluatePosition(T &p, bool me)
    {
        struct Helper {
            T maxP;
            int maxScore;

            int DoEval(T &p, bool me)
            {
                int score = 0;
                if(p.isGameOver()){
                    return p.score(me);
                }
                else{
                    std::vector<T> nextMoves = p.getNextPositions();
                    for(int i=0; i != nextMoves.size(); i++){
                        score += DoEval(nextMoves[i],!me);
                        if(score > maxScore){
                            p.display();
                            maxScore = score;
                            maxP = p;
                            p.display();
                        }
                    }
                    return score;
                }
            }
        } helper;

        return helper.DoEval(p, me);
    }
};
```